# Take value of a cell and store it in a variable for given values of column and row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to trace back value of X and store it as a variable for given values of columns and rows.

in this case, table is relation between yield strength and slenderness ratio, provided in local building byelaws, I want to use it in a script (Rest API) and call it through flask (local host) in flutter app.

I am storing table as libre-calc/csv file, should I use sql-lite?
I have tried using pandas

example, i want python to take value of sigma(pink) if value of yield strength is 250 and value of slenderness ratio is 60:
[table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whhkg.png)

Stuck for couple of weeks, help will be so appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pandas solution, [`DataFrame.at()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at) should work. You'd do `df.at[60, 250]`, but this will only work if those values exist as row/column labels.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both values you need are on the same row it's easy to operate with them, if you want to use pandas you can simply add a new column with the desire value you need.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Jack', 'Maria', 'Alan', 'Casey'],
        'Salary':[2400, 3000, 2000, 1700],
        'Rent_Cost':[900, 850, 550, 650]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Salary_%_Spent'] = round((df['Rent_Cost']/df['Salary']*100), 2)
```

This would result in:

[image]

Now if you prefer this as a variable...

```
percentageSpent = round((df['Rent_Cost']/df['Salary']*100), 2)
```

If you already have the column with the values you need then it becomes way easier.

```
percentageSpent = df['Salary_%_Spent']
```

or

```
caseyPercentage = df['Salary_%_Spent'][df['Name']=='Casey']
```

I hope this helps you, or at least guide you to solve your issue.